# How to specialize variadic template class for one type?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I am trying to specialize variadic template class for specific type.

I am trying to achieve this:

```
template<typename... Ts>
class myclass
{
   ///...
};

template<>
class myclass<int... N>
{
   ///...
};
```

And I get this errord:

```
error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'int', expected 'expression'
error C2187: syntax error: '...' was unexpected here
error C2065: 'N': undeclared identifier
error C2913: explicit specialization; 'ex::vec' is not a specialization of a class templa
```

Can anyone please hint what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't specialize a class, defined for types, with values.

Comment: How do you intend to use it? Please add examples.

Comment: To make sure I understand, you'd like your specilization to handle `myclass<int>` or `myclass<int, int>` or `myclass<int, ..., int>`, correct?

Comment: @NathanOliver, correct.

Comment: Please provide example of use case(s) of that template. Your definition example doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MarekR, I think my question is straightforward.
I want myclass<string, vector<int>> to behave one way and myclass<int>, myclass<int,int,int>. myclass<int,int> to behave another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `myclass` is declared for a variadic list of template parameter

```
template<typename... Ts>
class myclass
```

You can specialize if for specific types, not for specific values, as in your question (corrected for syntax, but remain wrong for the types/values problem)

```
template <int N>
class myclass<N...>
```

Different if you have the values as template parameter of a class, something as

```
template <typename ... Ts>
class myclass
 { };

template <template <int...> class C, int ... Is>
class myclass<C<Is...>>
 { };

// ...

template <int ...>
class foo 
 { };

// ...

myclass<foo<0, 1, 2>>  m0; // uses specialization
```

Comment: template<typename... Ts>
class myclass {};


template<int N>
class myclass<N...> {};

this one is giving me errors: 'myclass': template parameter 'Ts' is incompatible with the declaration
'Ts': parameter pack expects a type template argument

Comment: @EduardRostomyan - Is incompatible because the class is declared receiving a list of types (`typename...`) so the specialization can't, directly, receive a list of `int` values. More: you declare `N` as a single `int` value, so you can't expand it (`N...`) as a variadic pack.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is a workaround for your problem, rather than a direct solution.
Handling parameter packs directly might be quite tricky, so let's add an indirection level. Instead of trying to specialize your variadic template, you could ["wrap" the parameter pack](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yi4FXWwdRb6mMv14) with another template:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class... T>
struct wrapper;

// Uses C++17 metafunction for brevity
template <class T, class... Ts>
struct all_same : std::conjunction<std::is_same<T, Ts>...> 
{};

template <class T, class Enable = void>
struct test;

template <template <class...> class Wrapper, class... Ts>
struct test<Wrapper<Ts...>, std::enable_if_t<all_same<Ts...>::value>>
{};

int main()
{
    test<wrapper<int, int>> t;
    //test<wrapper<int, double>> t1; // won't compile, as we haven't defined the primary template
}
```